# Sort a multimap with respect to another list?

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, multimap

Given a certain order of keys, how can I sort a multimap (list of tuples with duplicate keys) with respect to this list, where the order of duplicate elements doesn't matter?

I'm looking for a function with the following signature

```
sortByList :: [(a,b)] -> [a] -> [(a,b)]
```

such that, for instance,

```
a = [(1,'a'), (2, 'b'), (102, 'c'), (2, 'z')]
b = [2,102,1]
sortByList a b   --    [(2,'b'), (2,'z'), (102, 'c'), (1, 'a')]
                 -- or [(2,'z'), (2,'b'), (102, 'c'), (1, 'a')] 
                 -- (order in duplicate keys irrelevant)
```

I have some ideas how to implement this, but they all seem ugly and cumbersome (using `lookup` and repeated find-and-delete on the given multimap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should be fairly optimal:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import qualified Data.Map as M

sortByList :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [a] -> [(a, b)]
sortByList xs ys = map snd $ sortBy (comparing fst) [(pos (fst x), x) | x <- xs]
  where order = M.fromList $ zip ys [1..]
        pos x = M.findWithDefault 0 x order
```

If `xs` has length *n* and `ys` has length *m*, the run time of this should be *O(n log n + (m + n) log m)*, which is *O(n log n)* if *m* is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 4):

`elemIndex` is the function you need:

```
import Data.List (sortBy, elemIndex)
import Data.Function (on)

sortByList :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [a] -> [(a,b)]
sortByList m as = sortBy (compare `on` (flip elemIndex as . fst)) m
```

It puts the keys which are not in the list in front, because `Nothing < Just 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a far from optimal suggestion:

```
import Data.List

sortByList :: (Eq a) => [(a,b)] -> [a] -> [(a,b)]
sortByList toSort order = reverse (go [] toSort order)
    where
      go result xs [] = xs ++ result
      go result xs (k:ks) = go (matches ++ result) unmatches ks
          where
            (matches, unmatches) = partition ((==k) . fst) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List 
sortByList::(Ord a,Ord b)=>[(a,b)]->[a]->[(a,b)]
sortByList m [] = m
sortByList m (x:xs) = sort(filter (\(a,b)->a==x) m)++ sortByList (filter (\(a,b)->a/=x) m) xs
```

Ugly code but it works

```
import Data.List 
sortByList::(Ord a,Ord b)=>[(a,b)]->[a]->[(a,b)]
sortByList m [] = m
sortByList m (x:xs) = let t = filter (\(a,b)->a==x) m in sort t ++ sortByList (m\\t) xs
```